# Package React Frontend into an executabe .jar

Tags: reactjs, maven

I am creating a simple Single Page application with React, using create-react-app. At this time, only frontend. No backend.

Problem is, the company wants me to package it into an executable .jar file, ideally using maven.

Now I found the plugin "[frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)". And I was able to create and run an example Hybrid project, following this tutorial [here](https://frakton.com/utilizing-maven-front-end-plugin-for-angular-spring-boot/). It is Angular, however, but this isn't the problem.

My problem is, I can only find solutions with Spring Boot (like [this](https://medium.com/@itzgeoff/including-react-in-your-spring-boot-maven-build-ae3b8f8826e), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257057/package-spring-boot-application-inside-a-react-app-with-maven) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039276/integrate-create-react-app-into-maven-build-process)). It seems impossible to package a pure frontend application into an executable .jar without Spring Boot. But my application has no backend.

Has anyone had the same problem and knows what to do? My attempt is creating a new Maven project, include the (react) frontend project and configure the POM accordingly, to get an executable .jar. But this doesn't work.